# Restrict C# features for solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syntax, compilation, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on some big software using Visual Studio 2010. My computer has also installment of Visual Studio 2017. Somehow I can use some C# syntax that is properly compiled on my computer (in VS 2010) and is not compiled on other computers (not having VS 2017). I guess it has something to do with installed Net Framework version. Nobody is allowed to update their Net Framework versions, so is there any way to limit it on my computer? I still want to be allowed to use VS 2017 to develop but I want to be able to compile code with limited features like others.

Comment: what are the syntax errors?

Comment: I assume this is because of differences in the 'default' .net framework version between 2010 and 2017. In the solution explorer, pull open the Project properties. The target framework can be specified there. Opening 2010 projects in 2017 should be fine, just make sure you specify the same framework version when creating new projects in 2017. Note, in having 2017 installed, you'll have access to .Net framework versions not available to others.

Comment: Can you give an *example* of this syntax that compiles on your machine but not on others?

Comment: @programtreasures I don't have access to exact errors, but they are connected to using newer C# syntax. For example "expected" or "unexpected" ";".

Comment: @DanielleSummers All projects have "Target framework: .NET Framework 4". Same value is visible if I'll open project in VS2010 and VS2017.

Comment: @Xkonti `expected` and `unexpected` are not C# syntax; also - *is there a good reason* to still use VS2010 with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you maybe need to change the c# Language version (rather than the .Net Framework target version).  I don't have vs 2010 so can't check this, but try following steps here (this is for vs2013, hopefully 2010 is similar):

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St

Apparently 2010 should have a default version of 4 - perhaps it allows you to go higher if you have later compilers installed.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Unfortunatelly VS2010 don't allow me to choose C# 4. It shows only C# 3, but it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with VS2017, you can specify a C# version in the project xml configuration.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>5</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[MSDN reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)